# Is appropriate to ask Github Issues as questions on Bioacoustics SE?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I use the program Triton a lot, and so I "watch" the Github page. This means I get updates about any bugs or issues people might be having. Recently, [one was asked, and answered, within the Github issues framework](https://github.com/MarineBioAcousticsRC/Triton/issues/87). I think this issue may be helpful to others, and would be similar to what would make a good question on the Bioacoustics SE.

Is it appropriate to turn that issue into a question on here? Or is that just duplicating information that already exists on the internet?

I think that yes it would be appropriate, and it would not be wastefully duplicating (because I don't get the impression that so many people monitor the issues on Github like I do...but maybe I'm wrong!). But, before I ask/answer, I'd like to know what others think.

Comment: See this relevant Help Center page (as well as the blog post it links to): [Can I answer my own question?](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My view would be to go for it as a "question and own answer" but only if you judge that this question is *particularly* interesting and you explain why, and add some extra context for people not using this software. And probably it would be more transparent to add a link to this github discussion in your own response.

Comment: I agree on adding a link to the GitHub discussion. I have not posted the question because I decided it perhaps would not be relevant to the larger community. It’s a software specific error - just have to make sure the right modules are installed - so more like a bug almost and maybe not appropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

Did I understand your question correctly: you are asking about whether it's appropriate to *preemptively* turn an existing (and already solved) issue on Github into a question here, so people could find find it more easily - even though no one has actually asked this question here yet?

*Assuming I did understand it*: I'd assume someone having the same issue with Triton should be able to find this solution on Github by themselves using Google, so I don't see much point in "repeating" it here for the sake of repeating. What would be the advantage in doing that vs. just waiting for someone to actually ask this exact question, and *then* replying with a link to the existing Github issue? Taking it to a (ridiculous) extreme, we could end up with multiple questions created and immediately answered here *just in case someone else has this problem at some point in the future*...

I'm not necessarily against you doing what you suggested, I don't think there's any real harm in it (despite my last comment) - but I confess I don't think there's much to be gained either. I might be missing something though, so I'd be happy to hear what you and others have to say about it!

Comment: Yes, you understood exactly :) And appreciate your thoughts on it. Like you said I don't want to necessarily add questions just in case, but at this early stage I see some value in having it as an example question (of what kind of questions are good to ask here) since we are still sort of getting going. But I don't want to just take up space if it isn't actually useful!!

Comment: In particular, in addition to making sure that the question is actually on-topic/allowed here and a good fit for the Stack Exchange format – I think it's important to ensure that it'd actually be a "real question" that's relevant to the userbase here (e.g. a frequently asked question, or something that's likely to come up regardless). Basically, ensure that it'd be a good question and answer even if you weren't posting an already-answered question from elsewhere. (And don't plagiarize others' writing, of course.)